# How to tell uWSGI to prefer processes to threads for load balancing

Tags: python, multithreading, process, load-balancing, uwsgi

I've installed Nginx + uWSGI + Django on a VDS with 3 CPU cores. uWSGI is configured for 6 processes and 5 threads per process. Now I want to **tell uWSGI to use processes for load balancing until all processes are busy, and then to use threads if needed.** It seems uWSGI prefer threads, and I have not found any config option to change this behaviour. First process takes over 100% CPU time, second one takes about 20%, and another processes are mostly not used.

Our site receives 40 r/s. Actually even having 3 processes without threads is anough to handle all requests usually. But request processing hangs from time to time for various reasons like locked shared resources, etc. In such cases we have -1 process. Users don't like to wait and click the link again and again. As a result all processes hangs and all users have to wait.

I'd add even more threads to make the server more robust. But the problem is probably python GIL. Threads wan't use all CPU cores. So multiple processes work much better for load balancing. But threads may help a lot in case of locked shared resources and i/o wait delays. A process may do much work while one of it's thread is locked.

I don't want to decrease time limits until there is no another solution. It is possible to solve this problem with threads in theory, and I don't want to show error messages to user or to make him waiting on every request until there is no another choice.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So, the solution is:

1. Upgrade uWSGI to recent stable version (as roberto suggested).
2. Use --thunder-lock option.

Now I'm running with 50 threads per process and all requests are distributed between processes equally.

Answer (score 10):

Every process is effectively a thread, as threads are execution contexts of the same process.

For such a reason there is nothing like "a process executes it instead of a thread". Even without threads your process has 1 execution context (a thread). What i would investigate is why you get (perceived) poor performances when using multiple threads per process. Are you sure you are using a stable (with solid threading support) uWSGI release ? (1.4.x or 1.9.x)

Have you thought about dynamically spawning more processes when the server is overloaded ? Check the uWSGI cheaper modes, there are various algorithm available. Maybe one will fit your situation.

The GIL is not a problem for you, as from what you describe the problem is the lack of threads for managing new requests (even if from your numbers it looks you may have a too much heavy lock contention on something else)

Comment: When I say "processes instead of threads for load balancing" I mean I want to balance threads usage between processes instead of pushing all requests to a single process unless it's 100% busy. Threads are not really parallel within single process in Python because of GIL. What about uWSGI 1.4? Have it got better load balancing algorithm? I use Ubuntu LTS with uwsgi 1.0.3 (hope it's stable in lts). Does it really make sense to update it? I also thought about cheaper mode, but it's mostly to solve the thundering herd problem. But I don't feel there is lack of threads, most of them are not used.

Comment: anything < 1.4 is unsupported and buggy. 1.0 is more than 2 years old and in the mean time uWSGI evolved (and improved) a lot. As the main uWSGI author i can say that anything < 1.4 has nothing to do with what uWSGI currently is.

Comment: "As the main uWSGI author" is a telling argument! You had to start with this one :) Thank you for explanation, I'm just happy to receive an answer from uWSGI author. May be you can explain briefly what is the current logic to choice a thread for request processing in 1.9? Could you please?

Comment: it is choosen by the kernel favouring performances (with the default locking setup). Some users prefer the workers to choosen in a round robin fashion so they force the use of ipc semaphores (--lock-engine ipcsem). I suggest you to start with default 1.9 setup to check if it is better than before (1.0)

Comment: Thank you. I'll try and report.

Comment: Magration to 1.9 solved the problem. --thunder-lock option does exactly what I want even without changing the lock engine. Thank you for the advice!